# VMWARE on Windows 7: Access Guest OS Webserver by Using Host Name

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vmware, hostname

I have a VMWARE Workstation installation on my Windows 7 box hosting an Ubuntu VM guest; the networking mode is setup as 'Bridged'. The guest OS gets its own IP address from the corporate DHCP server.

I have a LAMP environment installed on the guest VM. I can launch Firefox on the guest OS and type either `'http://localhost'` or `'http://myguestmachinename'` and the local web pages show up fine. However, in the host machine I can only access access the guest by typing its IP address; I'd like to share the guest OS web pages with others and so the changing IP address model is not good.

With similar network setup I have some Windows guest OS hosting web pages and they can be accessed fine by using the hostnames. So there is something different about Ubuntu and/or Apache--perhaps something that needs to be configured in that guest OS.

Here are the outputs from various files

```
interfaces file
```

> The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

```
The primary network interface
```

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

```
hosts file
```

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1       mylocalubuntu

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

```
hostname file
```

mylocalubuntu

```
sources.list file
```

## various apt sources

Any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check that the following are configured in ubuntu:

/etc/network/interfaces

/etc/hosts

/etc/hostname

/etc/apt/sources.list

make sure your hostname does NOT have underscores.

If none of the above works, consider adding enabling ssh access between guest OS's.

Comment: Not sure what I should have been looking for in these files but I have modified the original question and added various outputs for these files. As far as I can tell they look alright? BTW, I have also disabled Firewall in the guest--for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Corporate DHCP and Linux don't always cooperate. Assuming your VM is using eth0 and that the hostname is "myhostname," add this to /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    hostname myhostname
```

(Edited because original instructions were for Red Hat, not Ubuntu.)

And then "sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0."
After that run an nslookup of your hostname. If you're lucky your corporate DNS will return the proper bridged address.